# Not able to convert "00:30 AM" to 24 hours by strptime python

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, strptime, python-datetime

I am trying to convert "00:30 AM" to 24 hours time but it gives `ValueError: time data '00:30 AM' does not match format '%I:%M %p'`

The code used is:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('00:30 AM','%I:%M %p')
```

Can somebody please help me solving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%I` format expects a number between *one* and twelve, not zero and twelve. A 12 hour clock always uses `12` for midnight or noon.

From the [`strftime()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> `%I`
>   Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   01, 02, ..., 12

Either replace the `00` with `12` or use a different method of parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what can be the other way of parsing this?

Comment: You could catch the exception, remove the `AM` from the string and parse as a 24 hours timestamp?